# How to call intent based on item position in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i want to make an intent from array of images, but i don't know how to use `position`. the intent doesn't match with the layout i created.

here's the code:

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private int[] mImages = new int[] { R.drawable.kuhp_a,
            R.drawable.kuhp_b, R.drawable.kuhp_c };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        Context context = MainActivity.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);

        Button btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

        if (position == 0) {
            btnOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstAct.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        } else if (position == 1) {
            btnOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            SecondAct.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        } else if (position == mImages.length - 1) {
            btnOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdAct.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        }

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

        return imageView;
    }
```

firstact:

```
public class FirstAct extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.buku_satu);

    }
```

secondact and third have same code like first act, but it has different layout.

Comment: have you tried this way?

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private int[] mImages = new int[] { R.drawable.kuhp_a, R.drawable.kuhp_b, R.drawable.kuhp_c };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        Context context = MainActivity.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);

        final Button btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstAct.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondAct.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThirdAct.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

            }
        });

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't match perfectly :(

Comment: can you post your whole activity so that i can figure out the problem

Comment: sure, i have a problem with case 2. it shows random layout between layout one and layout three. i have no problems with others.